# Configure Spring Security in Mule using jdbc-provider

Tags: mysql, spring, security, http, mule

I have the following Mule App, which i'm trying to securing it with Spring Security using a database to provide the users (jdbc-provider).

I correctly configured the mysql database and the mysql jdbc driver in the classpath of the Mule App, but when i try to login i am getting the following error:

> Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:80 (null)

**Mule App (Based in Mule ESB 3.6.1):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
     xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.1/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <spring:property name="username" value="root"/>
            <spring:property name="password" value="sonar"/>
        </spring:bean>

  <ss:authentication-manager  alias="authenticationManager">
      <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
      </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
  </spring:beans>

  <mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="jdbc-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
  </mule-ss:security-manager>

  <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

  <flow name="SpringExample">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <logger level="INFO" message="## received" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="jdbc-provider"/>      
    <logger level="INFO" message="## passed security" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
INFO  2015-03-27 21:31:04,255 [[spring-security-maven].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ## received
ERROR 2015-03-27 21:31:04,299 [[spring-security-maven].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Authentication Attempt Failed. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (java.sql.SQLException)
  java.sql.DriverManager:596 (null)
2. Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException)
  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:80 (null)
3. Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException)
  org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider:85 (null)
4. Authentication Attempt Failed. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
  org.mule.security.MuleSecurityManager:91 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Mule issue. Add the jar to

```
<MULE_PATH>/mule-standalone-3.x.0/lib/mule
```

and

```
<MULE_STUDIO_PATH>/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.x.xxxx/mule/lib/mule
```

Comment: For me it was `<MULE_SDK_PATH>/lib/opt`

Answer (score 0):

By default mole doesn't provide jdbc driver for respective DB connectivity. We need to explicitly add jars to class path of project development.